# How to Move a Text Pattern Horizontally Using CMD or Cygwin CLI Tool?

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed, cmd, cygwin

I don't know if this is even possible in command line, but anyway, here is what I want to do:

I have a text file written like that

```
- FileName1.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
- FileName4.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt
- FileName5.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt
```

As you can see, the text was written randomly (somehow), which means that some files have an address, and some of them don't, so I can't Apply any rule on these lines like arranging\sorting and so ever, or I'm gonna lose the files "Names,Addresses" arrangement.

So, first I had to Move All of the addresses lines, one step up (that was the easy part in GUI), and I was able to do it using **Np++/TextPad** Regex as follow:- Find:`\nhttp`  -  Replace:`http` , The final result was like this:

Step.1:-

```
- FileName1.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
- FileName4.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt
- FileName5.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt
```

Now, The worst part (at least for me) is to move the matching pattern to the beginning of their lines, Exactly Like This:

Step.2:-

```
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt- FileName1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt- FileName4.txt 
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt- FileName5.txt
```

and now I can easily sort them, or whatever I need without any risk.
So, my question is:-

In Command Line **CMD** or **Cygwin** :-

1- How to Find "**\n**http" , and Replace with " http" ?

2- How to Move The Matching Patterns (File Address, From **http** to **.txt**), to the beginning of their Lines ?

also if there is any other technique, it would be great to know it.

Thanks a lot guys for the help you're offering, in such a great community. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` command which, I think, does what you want:

```
$ awk '/^http/{print $0 last;last="";next} last {print last} {last=$0} END{if (last) print last;}' file2
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt- FileName1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt- FileName4.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt- FileName5.txt
```

#### How it works

The script has one variable, `last` which contains the contents of the previous line.  `awk` implicitly loops over every line in the input file

- `/^http/{print $0 last;last="";next}`

  If the current line starts with `http`, then print it and the previous line together.  Set `last` to empty and skip the remaining commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `last {print last}`

  If the `last` variable is not empty, print it.  This only happens if there was no URL to go with the `last` line.
- `{last=$0}`

  Update the `last` variable with the current line.  In `awk`, `$0` denotes the whole of the current line.
- `END{if (last) print last;}`

  At the end of the input, if there is still a line in `last`, print it.  This only happens if the last line was a file name which lacked a URL.

#### Doing just the first step in `sed`

As long as `file` is not too big, this will work:

```
$ sed  ':a;N;$!b a;s/\nhttp/ http/g' file
- FileName1.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
- FileName4.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt
- FileName5.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt
```

This works by reading the entire file into sed's pattern space and then substituting to replace `\nhttp` with `http`.

In more detail:

- `:a;N;$!b a`

  This is a loop.  `:a` is a label.  `N` reads the next line into the pattern space.  `b a` jumps to label `:a`.  We want to continue this loop until the end of the file.  The last line in the file is called `$` and `!` means not.  So, `$!b a` means jump to label `:a` unless we have reached the last line of the file.
- `s/\nhttp/ http/g`

  Now that we have the whole of the file in the pattern space, we do a global substitution replacing `\nhttp` with `http`.

This is a variation on the above.  It reads lines into the pattern space until it reaches a line that starts with `http`.  Then, it removes the newline from in front of that line:

```
$ sed ':a;N;/http/!b a; s/\nhttp/ http/' file
- FileName1.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
- FileName4.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt
- FileName5.txt http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt
```

Since this approach doesn't read the whole file in at once, it is easier on memory if the file is large.

In more detail:

- `:a;N;/http/!b a`

  Just as above, this is a loop.  It keeps branching back to label `:a` to read another line until we get a line that includes `http`.
- `s/\nhttp/ http/`

  This replaces the newline in front of `http` with a space.

Comment: Thanks so much bro, I'm really Impressed!!
How could you think of something like that ?! I didn't even need to modify the pattern in your command! However, please allow me to ask you (Just for Knowledge) How to do the first step in **CLI**? I mean, in NP++, I've used this, Find: **\nhttp** - Replace: **http** to move the **http** lines one step up, so how to do the same thing using for example **sed** or **perl** ? ... Really Appreciate your help...karim

Comment: @ENG.KARIM Thanks.  I have added to the answer an example of just doing the first step in `sed`.

Comment: Back! I Just Came Back to Say Thank You John, I Do Appreciate Your Help. You Can't Imagine How Much Time You Saved For Me...Thanks Again

Comment: BTW, **potong**'s Code is Great Too, But Your Hint About The Size of The File, Made Me Somehow Worry about Using `Sed` , As I almost have 10.000 Line in Each File!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/(^-.*)\n(http.*)/\2\1/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines at a time and swap line 2 for line 1 (removing the newline) if the pattern matches. Those lines that do not match are printed as is.

Comment: I wish If I was able to Vote up for your answer, but as you can see I can't do that yet...
Thank You So Much Bro, Your Command is Perfect. Have a Good Time :)

Answer (score 0):

This short Perl program will do as you ask.

Be careful to backup your original file, as it modifies the file in-place.

The path to the file to be edited is passed as a parameter on the command line, like this

```
perl edit_file.pl mytext.txt
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', shift or die $!;

for ( my $i = 1; $i < @file; ) {

  if ( $file[$i] =~ m<^http://>i ) {
    $file[$i] .= $file[$i-1];
    splice @file, $i-1, 1;
    next;
  }

  ++$i;
}
```

**result**

```
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-1.txt- FileName1.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName3.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-4.txt- FileName4.txt
http://example.com/AnyName-For-File-5.txt- FileName5.txt
```